# Represent text in column headers as dates in Excel

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, excel-2013

Let me rephrase my question.. I have date columns, as in the column headers are individual date (example: Col A = 02/24/2014, Col B = 02/25/2014, etc) with number values within them. I created a new column C which has the formula  = Col B - Col A. Naturally, the column header for Col C would display a **#VALUE!** error since the first row is being subtracted as well. This is done for the rest of the columns as well. In order to rename the new columns, I used the Go To Special option in Find and Select, to choose Formula > Error. This only highlights the new columns with the #VALUE! error. I then assign a new name to each of the new columns by concatenating the column headers from which they were subtracted. So Col C will become "Col A To Col B", i.e. "02/24/2014 To 02/25/2014".

I'm looking for a method with which I can copy and paste only the new columns to another sheet or at the very least copy and paste the whole sheet and then delete the individual date columns, example: Col A and Col B, leaving only the new columns, example: Col C.

Initially, before changing the new column names, I could have used the Go to Special option to select only those column headers which have text value in them. That would select only the individual date columns since the new columns will have error values. Again, I'm only referring to column headers over here but that's of course wrong.

Comment: I tried reading your question 3 times but still had no idea what you're asking. Some example would help.

Comment: I've rephrased the question. I hope it's more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for a method with which I can copy and paste only the new columns to another sheet or at the very least copy and paste the whole sheet and then delete the individual date columns, example: Col A and Col B, leaving only the new columns, example: Col C.

Correct me if I am wrong, but it sounds like all you need to do is create a new sheet, select the columns you have created by right clicking on the top of the column, selecting copy, and then using the Paste Special option to paste "Values" into your new sheet.

This will allow you to copy/paste the reults of your concatenate function instead of just pasting the function itself.

Let me know if this is what you were looking for.